# Como contornar o uso de palavras reservadas do banco de dados com hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring

Estou aprendendo a trabalhar com REST API em Java utilizando spring com hibernate e estou com o seguinte problema. Minha entidade possuí o nome `user` que é uma palavra reservada no banco de dados que estou utilizando(postgres), portanto quando executo o programa recebo o seguinte erro.

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id uuid not null, birthday date, email varchar(60) not null, password varchar(50) not null, username varchar(30) not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
> ...
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"

Criando manualmente essa tabela posso contornar esse problema utilizando as aspas duplas ao redor do nome da tabela. Existe uma forma de contornar esse erro na criação da minha entidade sem alterar o nome da tabela? 
 
  Segue o código da minha entidade:

```java
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(length = 30, unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @Column(length = 60, unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(nullable = true)
  private Date birthday;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>**Soluções encontradas no stackoverflow**<sup>En</sup></sub>

---

Nessa resposta: [Postgres DDL error: 'syntax error at or near “user”' [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222377/6797930) é da seguinte forma:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"User\"")
public class User implements UserDetails { ... }
```

porque, pode fazer o escape da *palavra-chave* da mesma forma em sua declaração de entidade.

Ou em outra resposta: [Unable to use table named “user” in postgresql hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350874/unable-to-use-table-named-user-in-postgresql-hibernate) da seguinte forma:

```
@Table(name="`users`")
```

ou seja, envolva o nome `user` com o sinal de crase.

---

No seu código algo assim resolve:

```
@Entity(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(length = 30, unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @Column(length = 60, unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(nullable = true)
  private Date birthday;
}
```

***ou***

```
@Entity(name = "`user`")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(length = 30, unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @Column(length = 60, unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(nullable = true)
  private Date birthday;
}
```

[Outros exemplos](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/quote/User.java#L31)